# Change sender on DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

How to send an template envelope using another user other than admin in a same account?

```
{
    "accountId": "cfd38770-f77a-4b7a-b4b2-e305e4ca2de0/",
     "sender": {
        "userName": "Zalman Kagan",
        "userId": "85354f2c-7c48-42b1-8b7e-ca43099eb722",
        "accountId": "cfd38770-f77a-4b7a-b4b2-e305e4ca2de0",
        "email": "zkegs@yahoo.com"
    },

    "emailSubject": "API Example - Populating Data in Templates",
    "templateId": "58740233-a060-4abc-8221-a81a87924969",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "vijudhai@gmail.com",
        "name": "Udhaya",
        "roleName": "Test",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "Text e322fdde-b5d4-498b-a203-22dd6821dc6e",
                "value": "9876543210"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your application can **impersonate** a user in your account. Then, any envelopes you create will have the impersonated user as the sender.

To impersonate someone in your account, use OAuth JWT grant to obtain an access token that impersonates the user.

You will need the user's user-id in guid form. You can either configure your app with the user-id(s) or you can first lookup the guid from the user's email.

To lookup the user's guid from their email: `GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users?email=users_email@example.com` [Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Users/Users/list). Note that it is possible for one email address to be associated with more than one person/more than one user.

You will also need **consent** from the user for your app to impersonate them. Consent can be granted administratively (blanket consent) or each user can grant consent individually. Consent is granted to your app once, thereafter your app can impersonate the user.

Comment: Thank you so much it will really helpful for me.